# How can ReLU ever fit the curve of x²?

Tags: machine-learning, activation-function

As far as I understand (pardon me if I am wrong) the activation functions in a neural network go through the following transformations:

1. Multiplication by constants(weights) to x ( $f(ax)$ , $f(x)$ being the activation function).
2. Recursive substitution $f(f(x))$.

Now with the above transformations a ReLU activation function should never be able to fit a x² curve. It can approximate, but as the input grows the error of that approximated function will also grow exponentially, right?

Now x² is a simple curve. How can ReLU perform better for real data which will be way more complicated than x²?

I am new to machine learning. So please pardon me if there are any blunders in anything I am assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It can approximate, but as the input grows the error of that approximated function will also grow exponentially, right?**

You are right, the neural network uses ReLu functions to approximate the output $f(x) = x^2$ and there is some error incurred, but you are forgetting that

1. Non-linear functions also do approximation since we use only some subset of activation functions and incur some error which can be as huge as with ReLus
2. There is also a number of neurons to consider. The more neurons/layers you have - the better the approximation can be (since more small-interval ReLus are fit to better approach the shape of $x^2$). If your input size grows, you should also consider increasing the number of neurons/layers, in this way the approximation will always be close enough.

**Now x² is a simple curve. How can ReLU perform better for real data which will be way more complicated than x²?**

The main reason for this is that even though other activation functions can approximate $x^2$ or something else better, they are not optimised as fast. Generally speaking, non-linear activation function decision surface is more complex than the loss created by ReLus and can contain better global minimum but this minimum is harder to find, and, thus, with the less sophisticated loss created by ReLus, we can find a better optima using some gradient descent procedure, and it will be much faster.

Comment: Wouldn't we prefer accuracy to speed. i mean we only need to get to the approximation once, don't we. Also is speed and simplicity the only reason reLU is considered better.

Comment: Speed here generally means that it is 1 month for tanh and 1 hour for Relu :) So, you find some optimum of ReLu loss in 1 hour, which gives you say 10% off prediction, or you find 1% off using tanh in 1 month, and 10% off in 1 week. This difference is prohibitive. And secondly, your loss function with tanh is much more difficult so you get stuck at local optima more than with ReLus, which results in always better optimum, say 10%for ReLus  vs 25% off with tanh. Time frames/optima are just for illustration - a hyperbola.

Comment: so basically when you use reLU the number of nodes need to be high to match the complexity needed. and as its fast it will converge faster.

Comment: ReLu is used for the second reason - faster convergence, which due to limitation of computational resources/better behaving function results in better optima, which results in better performance metric results. As for the number of nodes - it works with any activation, not only ReLu.

Comment: yeah i get the faster part. But what i mean is the final approximation accuracy that reLU can ever reach will always be less than what other (curvy) functions can achieve right?. When i mean always i mean when it comes to fitting curves like x^2

Comment: @AdithyaSama, yes, if you increase the number of neurons for ReLus, and not increase their number for other functions. Now, if you have say the same number of neurons for both ReLu network (say, global minimum is 5, local minima - 6, 7, 8) vs Sigmoid network (global minima is 4, local minima 5, 6, 7), you run gradient descent on both for 1 hour. Now, you have found your local minima for your ReLu at 7. For Sigmoid, you are still at 8, because your optimization has not completed. Moreover, after 1 more hour, your relu with restart found 5, and your sigmoid found 6, since its loss is harder

Comment: i guess that makes sense. When we talk about local minima its regarding the training data isn't it, But when reLU sees new data from for example the x^2 curve. Its error would be high wouldn't it as its too rigid while fitting. I can see why reLU would be better at classification. But based on what i read sigmoid and tanh are better at classification :). I Guess looking at it all wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are right.

A 2 layer NN with ReLU activations can't approximate the function $x \rightarrow x^2$.

The function computed by a 2 layer NN is $\sum_i a_i ReLU(\sum_j b_{ij}x)$.

1. All the relu’s will be centered at 0. So we will just be adding a bunch of rays originating from 0. The sum of these will be a ray originating from 0.
2. We add an extra constant 1 input to our single input $x$. This is similar to adding bias to every neuron and allows the rays to shift.
3. To approximate we begin with a ray of slope 0, then we go on adding shifted-relus to account for the increase in slope as we move towards positive $x$. Similarly, we add shifted negated relu’s for negative $x$.

**Conclusion**: you need bias terms if you want to approximate $x \rightarrow x^2$.

Also, from the above construction, it is clear that a finite number of neurons will only allow you to approximate the map in a bounded range around 0.